# reactjs : get the counts of sub-categories based on the id with api?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a loop that receives and displays categories from the server. Now I want to send the ID of each category to the server and return the number of sub-categories. How can I do this?

JSX Loop :

```
<tbody>
  {maincategorylist.map((maincat, index) => (
    <tr key={maincat.id}>     
      <td>
        {maincat.categoryName}
        //display count of subcategory
      </td>
      
    </tr>
  ))}
</tbody>
```

I also wrote a function, but I could not use it.

```
const handleCount = (id) => {
    axios
      .get(`Adminbarber/GetCountSubCategories/${id}`, {
        headers: {
          Authorization: "Bearer " + admintoken,
        },
      })
      .then((res) => {
        
        // setCount(res.data) ;
         console.log(res.data);
         return res.data;
      });
  };
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community Obviously, every category has sub-categories. I have a function that receives the number of sub-categories of each category from the back-end. I want to display the number of sub-categories in the row of each category.

for example : car (3)

Comment: "but I could not use it" isn't very clear. What went wrong? What happened when you called that function?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend creating another component that specifically handles this functionality for you. It makes it reusable and allows you to separate the lifecycle of the data/component for subcategory counts from the data/component of the table and categories.

It might look something like this:

```
function SubcategoryCount(props) {
    const { categoryId } = props;
    const [subcategoryCount, setSubcategoryCount] = useState(0);

    // You'll also want to handle idle, loading, and error states visually
    // For example, showing a spinner, or not showing a count until success

    // Handles fetching data (though I prefer react-query)
    useEffect(() => {
        let shouldCancel = false;

        handleCount(categoryId)
            .then((data) => {
                // A new category id was provided, or we unmounted. Do not call state changes
                if (shouldCancel) return; 
                setSubcategoryCount(data.count); // Or however its structured
            })
            .catch((e) => {
                // TODO: Log error, set error state for rendering
            });

        return () => {
            shouldCancel = true;
        };
    }, [categoryId]);

    // I believe you can just return a string without any elements around
    // it but I wrapped it in a React Fragment just in case
    return (
        <>
            `(${subcategoryCount})`
        </>
    );
}
```

And then you can simply:

```
<tbody>
  {maincategorylist.map((maincat, index) => (
    <tr key={maincat.id}>     
      <td>
        {maincat.categoryName}
        <SubcategoryCount categoryId={mainCat.id} />
      </td>
      
    </tr>
  ))}
</tbody>
```